# Kentico Forcing New Website

Tags: kentico

I have backed up the Kentico Database and website from one of our Live servers and placed it within our Dev server and configured the website in IIS.

When I navigate to the website, it currently asks for New installation.. Whereas it should just show me the current website.

How do I get it to show the website?

**EDIT**

The following error occurs when going ahead and creating a new instance with the restored Database:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Restore the backed up database and add database connection string to the web.config of the application. Simple as that :)

Answer (score 2):

Who or what is set as the DB objects owner/schema in the DB? Does this match the setting in Site Manager (or, CMS_SettingsKey table)? I would make sure these two match.
Another option is that the connection string was not initialized by .Net - I would do a dummy change in the web.config file to force the app restart and/or also clearing the .Net cache.

Comment: I have applied dummy changes to the web.config and relaunched the page. Please check the edit i have made.

Comment: Have you checked the DB schema as JurajO suggested? What is default schema of your user and does it match the schema of the tables in your database?